# TextInput field not fetching value inside Map function react-native

Tags: react-native

i want to fetch 'DeliveredQuantity' in Textinput Field, do anyone  know solution for this

```
const [arrayList, setArraylist]= [
         {id:0, ExpectedQuantity:10, DeliveredQuantity:7},
         {id:1, ExpectedQuantity:19, DeliveredQuantity:9},
         {id:2, ExpectedQuantity:11, DeliveredQuantity:11},
         {id:3, ExpectedQuantity:45, DeliveredQuantity:30},
     ]

arrayList.map((items,index)=>{ 

     return
            <TextInput  value={items.DeliveredQuantity} />

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the array in a state and use it like this

```
const [arrayList, setArraylist] = React.useState([
    { id: 0, ExpectedQuantity: 10, DeliveredQuantity: 7 },
    { id: 1, ExpectedQuantity: 19, DeliveredQuantity: 9 },
    { id: 2, ExpectedQuantity: 11, DeliveredQuantity: 11 },
    { id: 3, ExpectedQuantity: 45, DeliveredQuantity: 30 },
  ]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {arrayList.map((items, index) => (
        <TextInput value={items.DeliveredQuantity} />
      ))}
    </View>
  );
```

[Working Example](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/many-inputs)

Comment: i tried but nothing is displaying inside textinput